# При транскрибации не выделить одного из двух говорящих

Tags: python, python-openai

Использовал pyannote-audio (diarization) для определения 2-ух спикеров. Но нужно выделить только одного из них и транскрибировать. Это возможно?
Использовал:

```
from pyannote.audio import Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline.from_pretrained(
 "pyannote/speaker-diarization-3.1",
 use_auth_token="token")

import torch
pipeline.to(torch.device("cuda"))

diarization = pipeline("filepath")

for turn, _, speaker in diarization.itertracks(yield_label=True):
 print(f"start={turn.start:.1f}s stop={turn.end:.1f}s speaker_{speaker}")
```